# Max and Number of occurrences

Tags: java, count, max

In my lab, we have to have the user input numbers, until they enter '0'. The program will then find the max, count the number of occurrences, and output both numbers.

Here's my code:

```
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, count = 0, num;

  System.out.println ("Enter a number (Enter a 0 to stop): ");
     num = scan.nextInt();

  while (num != 0){
     System.out.println ("Enter a number: ");
     num = scan.nextInt();
     if (num >= max){
        max = num;
        count ++;
     }
  }
     System.out.println("\nMax number was: " + max);
     System.out.println("Number of occurrences: " + count);
```

Now when it outputs, sometimes I get the right answer and sometimes not. I figure I just have the loop wrong or maybe the counter needs to be reset, but I can't figure it out.

For example:

If I enter: 3, 5, 2, 5, 5, 5, 0

The output reads: 
    Max number was: 5
    Number of occurrences: 4

But if I enter: 3, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9, 0

The output reads: 
Max number was: 9
Number of occurrences: 3

Just looking for some advice.

Answer (score 2):

If `num > max`, then it's the first occurrence of the max, and `count` should be set to 1. If `num == max`, then it's another occurrence of the max, and `count` should be incremented.

Also, as @doelleri correctly mentions in a comment, the first number is ignored.

Comment: Also the first input is being ignored.

Comment: I thought that actually after I posted this, and I was trying to fix it. Realized it should be a 'do-while' loop instead of 'while'. Thanks! :D

Comment: It doesn't have to be a do while loop. Just don't read any int before the loop. Initialize num to any value except 0.

Answer (score 1):

The best loop to use here is the `do...while`

Here is a correction to your code :

You'll have to reset the `count` variable only if a new `max` is found.

```
          do{
             System.out.println ("Enter a number: ");
             num = scan.nextInt();
             if (num > max){
                max = num;
                count = 1;
             } else if (num == max){
                 count++;
             }
          }while (num != 0);

          System.out.println("\nMax number was: " + max);
          System.out.println("Number of occurences: " + count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your count variable when a new maximum is found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **reset the counter** when ever you observe a new max value. Also you should use `do-while` instead of a `while` loop. Because `do-while` loop always executes once, so you can take the user input in the loop.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, count = 0, num;
    System.out.println ("Enter a number (Enter a 0 to stop): ");
    do {
      System.out.println ("Enter a number: ");
      num = scan.nextInt();
      if (num >= max){
        count = num == max ? count+1 : 1;
        max = num;
      }
    }while(num != 0);
    System.out.println("\nMax number was: " + max);
    System.out.println("Number of occurences: " + count);
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I got it to work. I'm a nub, so I'm still working on correct loop usage.